# Creating a Google-style background image fader?

Tags: jquery, background-image, fadein

Hey guys. If you haven't already seen, Google has the ability to add a custom background image (for better or worse) and I was wondering how to achieve the same fade-in-on-load effect using jQuery.

Any ideas?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383870/jquery-how-do-you-get-an-image-to-fade-in-on-load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383870/jquery-how-do-you-get-an-image-to-fade-in-on-load "Ho Do You Get An Image To Fade On Load") Check this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a method for this purpose, `fadeIn`.  See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) for explanation.

> .fadeIn( [ duration ], [ callback ] )
>
> durationA string or number determining
>   how long the animation will run.
>
> callbackA function to call once the
>   animation is complete.

As an aside, fade is often implemented to use javaScript to continually modify the [opacity](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp) of an element.

Comment: +1 And here's a link to the JQuery API for the `fadeIn` function, if you need it :)
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 0):

The real question is how do they resize the image on resizing the browser ... fading it in is easy :)
you can also do  $("#selectdiv").hide().animate({opacity : 1});

I think fadeIn is just a shortcut to that annyway