# Load a div once image is loaded using jquery

Tags: jquery, image, pageload

On page load, my image slider takes a second or two to load, and the shading image below it appears immediately(very small file size as compared to the slider image). You can see it here: [homepage](http://vitaminjdesign.com/IAM/)

I would like the shading image to load only after the slider image has completed it's load. It would be even nicer to apply a nice elegant fade in effect once the first slider image completes it load.

I can't seem to figure out how to write this in jquery. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the images `onload` event.

Using jQuery it would look like

```
$('#image_id').load(function() {
     $('#div_id').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

If you're inserting the image(s) dynamically you can just put that into the creator object:

```
$('<img>', {
    src:   '/myimages/foo.jpg',
    id:    'bar',
    load:  function() {
        $('#div_id').fadeIn('fast');
    }
}).appendTo(#somewhere);
```

Ref.: [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)
Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/20/

Comment: @JCHASE11: I added an example link.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an onload on the image.

Use jQuery to bind the onload onto the slider's images and hide the shadow by default.

```
$('#img').bind("load", function() {
    $('#theshadow').show();
});
```

Of course you will need a way to do this with your slider (which has multiple images and other features).  But the load event on the image should be what you want.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383870/jquery-how-do-you-get-an-image-to-fade-in-on-load/2526590#2526590), it is related