# displayDiv.fadeIn('3000'); does not fade slowly on this webpage

Tags: javascript, css, html, fadein

Technically displayDiv.fadeIn('3000'); should fade in the image slowly but on this page it does not:

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/BpXbn/3/ (on hover of "ice white image")

Is there a possible reason for this or a way to fix this so the fade in works instead please?

Kind regards,

Kelly

Comment: You probably should read up on how jsfiddle works. It's not a place to dump complete web pages.

Comment: @kelly: Probably, you are confused. fadeIn to be used in jQuery for ex: $('#logo').hide();.fadeIn(3000); Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383870/jquery-how-do-you-get-an-image-to-fade-in-on-load

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I could not get the original jsFiddle to work when I put only part of the code there so just put the whole page there. Thanks though will try and solve this first and update it. Will  keep all posted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in DOM method called "fadeIn". Perhaps you've seen it used in some jQuery code, or code from some other framework.  If you just get a DOM element from the browser via "getElementById()", however, what you get is a plain DOM element and that has no such function.