# jquery imagesLoaded image by image

Tags: jquery, image, load

Ive been looking at a jquery solution that listens to when each image (out of a bunch) are loaded before executing some actions (fadein etc).

With `imagesLoaded` I've managed to do this when ALL images are loaded, but I would want it to execute on each image once its loaded independent of the state of the others.

I think this is possible with `imagesLoaded`, but havent managed to get that to work. Has anyone?

Other solution?

Comment: Thanks all for great suggestions. I went with using imagesLoaded in a loop for each image for now.

Answer (score 5):

Listen to the imagesLoaded progress event.

(https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

```
imagesLoaded("img").on("progress", function(imagesLoadedInstance, image) {
    // Code for each image
});
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, I completed your answer a bit here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25959401/2112538

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a function directly to the DOM like: `<img onload="executeThisImage(imgId);" />` ?

Or you can bind the load directly to it with jQuery like mipe34 suggests:

```
$("#myImage").load(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery:

```
$("#myImage").bind("load", function () { $(this).fadeIn(); });
```

or the same with different syntax:

```
$("#myImage").load(function(event) {
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Also check this interesting topics on SO:

- [jQuery How do you get an image to fade in on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383870/jquery-how-do-you-get-an-image-to-fade-in-on-load)
- [jQuery callback on image load (even when the image is cached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)

*The second one is really interesting one. There is a solution how to make it working even when the image is cached by the browser.*

Following the best answer on this topic. I see the best solution like:

```
$("#myImage").one('load', function() {
  $(this).fadeIn();
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Here is used [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for event binding to assure that event handler is executed at most once. The `each` loop will assure that if image is cached it will fire the load event on it.

Comment: `.on()` has been the [preferred method of attaching events since 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event for that:

```
$("img").load(function(event) {
    console.log(this);
});
```

It might be good idea to limit the code to some specific set of images. For example using a class:

```
$("img.foo").load(function(event) {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you first need to hide the image:

```
$('img').css('display', 'none');
```

Then fade it in when the `load` event fires:

```
$('img').load(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```